# Powershell - Automated Outlook 2013 signatures "Images not displaying in emails sent to recipients"

Tags: powershell, outlook, signature

I'm using an existing PS script that I've modified that is linked to Group Policy for
automated Outlook 2013 signatures for all of our end users. Everything works perfect with no issue's but for some reason I cannot get images to attach and send to the recipients. The image is a link at the bottom of the signature to Twitter which is nothing but a small 30x40 png. When I run the PS script it pulls in everything correctly (from AD) and updates my local "signature" folder within Outlook, and it looks correct before I send the email, but when I send the email internally or externally the recipient sees everything correctly except the "Twitter.png". The only object they see is a box with a red X but the link actually works. The image is located on my C drive under signatures and that's where the PS script is pulling the image from when create a new email.

Comment: You cannot use an image stored in your local signatures folder, because that is inaccessible to other users. You need to either send it along as attachment and embed it in the HTML email as `<img src='cid:twitter.jpg' />` or you could use an image on a public location on your company site. See [Embedding images in HTML email](https://mailtrap.io/blog/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/)

Comment: Sounds good. One question though, is it possible to have the image source on the local computer for the CID option? I was planning on creating a GPO that would push out the image to everyone's local computer then in Powershell point the script to that folder to attach the image within HTML so I'm assuming it would send the email with the image in the body of the Outlook email? I don't have a public server for this image .

Comment: Maybe something like this would work? $stream.WriteLine('img src="C:\ICONS\cid:Twitter.png" alt="img" ')

Answer (score 0):

Look at a signature with an image created by Outlook itself - the images are stored in a subfolder, and Outlook adds the image as an attachment.

Comment: I did try that but im doing something wrong within PS. Below is the code that works on my local computer after I run the PS script but the recipient will not see the image.

Comment: $stream.WriteLine('<v:imagedata src="Images/twitter.png" o:href="cid:twitter.png"/> ')
$stream.WriteLine('</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=42 height=40')
$stream.WriteLine('img src="Images/twitter.png" alt=Twitter v:shapes="Picture_x0020_6"><![endif]></span></a><a"')

Comment: It only shows a box with a Red X. The "Images" folder is located on my local computer in the Microsoft Signatures folder. I know the CID option will work, but I must be missing something. I got the code below from a computer that everything is working correctly but I created the signature manually through Outlook not PS.

Comment: The folder name must be `<signature_name>_files`. Again, compare to an existing signature.